# Why is this IIFE returning error undefined?

Tags: javascript, iife

Why is this returning: Uncaught ReferenceError: winConditions is not defined?

I'm returning winConditions in the function and then I run the function and then console.log(winConditions), why is it not working?

```
const gameBoard = (() => {
    
    

    const board = [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]

    let applyWinConditions = () => {  
        const winConditions = [[board[0], board[1], board[2]], [board[3], board[4], board[5]],
        [board[6], board[7], board[8]], [board[0], board[3], board[6]],
        [board[1], board[4], board[7]], [board[2], board[5], board[8]],
        [board[0], board[4], board[8]], [board[2], board[4], board[6]]];
        console.log("e")
        return {
            winConditions
        }
    };

    applyWinConditions();

    console.log(winConditions)

    return {
        applyWinConditions: applyWinConditions,
    }

})();
```

Comment: Your function ignores the value returned from `applyWinConditions()`.

Comment: You never assign the return value of `applyWinConditions()`. Something like this is all you need: `let winConditions = applyWinConditions(); console.log(winConditions)`

Comment: @romellem well `winConditions` is being returned as a property of an object, which also is probably wrong.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are trying to log a variable that is out of scope.

winConditions is defined inside applyWinConditions, thus not available outside, for console.log to see it.

try something like this:

```
console.log("winConditions", applyWinConditions());
```

you should see the return of your function, where winConditions has the value you'd expect.